# PHP Reading the URL

Tags: php, url

How do I make the following url to be read:

localhost/index.php?errormsg=wrongpassword

so I want it to set the variable $errormsg to 'wrongpassword' how do I do that? I am pretty sure there is a way using $_GET or $_POST?

Comment: try `$_GET['errormsg']`

Comment: A simple google search could have answered this for you, btw. We try to help, but a little more effort on your part always helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `$_GET['errormsg']`.

Something like this should do:

```
if isset($_GET['errormsg'])
{
    echo $_GET['errormsg'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem, I cannot use mysql_real_escape_string on it, so it is not safe to use because it can be SQL Injected.

Comment: Shouldn't stop it from being `echo`'d out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$errormsg = $_GET['errormsg']
```

This should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['errormsg']` is the answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($_GET)
```

to see all variables in the URL. in this case you want

```
$_GET['errormsg']
```

Answer (score 0):

You were as close as ever. A single google would've yielded the answer to you :)

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```
<?php
    // use htmlspecialchars() to clean up url-encoded characters
    $error_message = htmlspecialchars($_GET["errormsg"]);

    echo 'Error: ' . $error_message;
?>
```

`prints: "Error: error_here"`, if url = `...?errormsg=error_here`